# How to quickly add a curve around object?

Tags: add-on, bezier-curves

I did it recently with 2.8 version, it was somewhere in the N tab, I pressed a button, and the object was instantly covered with spiral curve. Cant find it in the current version. There is Curve Info panel, but nothing can be pushed there. I checked all curve addons to be on. How can I do it now?

Comment: This sounds like an add-on.

Comment: I didn`t install any curve addons but everything curve related is active, so maybe something changed.

Comment: The area that is opened by N has a tab called “create,“ and tools to make stuff for added to that tab with add-ons. I am certain this was an add-on.